# uwp not working in multiple user(app Crash)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

UWP App crashes in **User B** while the app is already running on another **User A**.

When the app in **User A** is stopped, then the app in **User B** Working Fine.

How do enable Both Users to open the app simultaneously?

***For example:***

**User1** opens the uwp application
without closing the application signing into another User(**User2**) then opening the uwp application, the app has been **crashed**

if **User1** closed the uwp app properly then in **User2** uwp app worked fine

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/multi-user-applications**

**I tried the above one but not working**

**Error Log**

Error: Invalid window handle.

This API must be called from a thread with a CoreWindow or a window must have been set explicitly.,    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() + 0x21
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task) + 0x70
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task) + 0x38
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task) + 0x17
at Info.CIS.UI.UWP.CloseApplication.d__7.MoveNext() + 0x14f

Comment: I haven't programmed for UWP, but according to that doc, **by default** apps are "single-user". That means each user running an app is **independent**: they are each running a separate copy of the app. So it isn't a "general" problem - IF the app stores documents in that user's document folder. There must be some **shared resource** that is causing the problem. For example, both attempting to access a file in a "common" location. Multi-user won't fix. **What line of code** does the crash happen on? Is there an exception message? A stack trace. Do basic debugging to **isolate** the problem.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks for your comment I attached the error log please have a look at it

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with that problem. Googling the error message didn't give any useful result either. I recommend making a new app. Without making any changes to the default app, do the same test. Is that new app able to run two users without crashing?